# Multiple accessing to singleton object in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, memory-management

I want to ask a question that comes my mind. This question about memory accessing, contains the object with singleton lifetime in asp.net core. So, suppose exists in this structure two thread. one of them is the normal request/response thread used in asp net. The other thread is continuous running worker service in  background.

My plan is create the task queue. And in the queue, I'm storing tasks I don't want execute in request/response thread. This stored functions is continuous executing in background.

**This code partition's contains to Task Queue. So this class using in background worker service and anywhere in asp.net.**

```
public class EventQueue : IEventQueue
{
            public LinkedList<Task> Queue = new LinkedList<Task>();
    
            public void AddEvent(Task task)
            {
                Queue.AddFirst(task);
            }
    
            public Task GetNextEvent()
            {
                var task = Queue.Last.Value;
                Queue.RemoveLast();
                return task;
            }
    }
```

**This code partition's contains to worker service. It's doing one by one execute in queue tasks**

```
public class QueueWorker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IEventQueue _queue;

        public QueueWorker(IEventQueue queue)
        {
            _queue = queue;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {         
                    var task = _queue.GetNextEvent();
                    if (task != null)
                        task.RunSynchronously();                
            }
        }
    }
```

**This code partition's contains to registered services.**

```
services.AddSingleton<IEventQueue,EventQueue>();
services.AddHostedService<QueueWorker>();
```

Questions:

- Does this structure work well? I think, It's will not work well bcs there is multiple access to queue instance. Or rather worker service is always accessing to queue instance. Therefore there will be no time to access for other threads. So this approach's right?
- if singleton lifetime wasn't used and EventQueue was static(at least LinkedList property was static), Would things be different?
- Do you have any suggestions for the improvement of this structure?

Comment: @quain's already provided you a solution, so I just point some problems in code example. ````LinkedList```` is not thread-safe, which means if multiple threads are entering in it's members (e.g. calling Add/Remove methods) they potentially mess up the internal structure of it. This is the main problem. But there is a second one in pattern used in your ````GetNextEvent```` method: getting the last value and removing it from the list separately is not thread-safe either! A second thread may get the last value too before the first one removes it!

Comment: I understand. I will use thread-safe object(with lock mechanism). According to answer below i have to use Concurrent Data Structures or Task.Factory.StartNew()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will advice against the handling of tasks on a seperate queue thread with a worker backround something.

Instead consider using async Tasks, .net is really good at pushing through data as each task has an own thread anyway this structure frees up your response thread enough:

```
[HttpGet("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(){
  return await Task<IActionResult>.Factory.StartNew(() => {
      //TODO: Your lengthy task here
  });
}
```

Now say you wanted a worker type object, does it have to be a singleton? i guess not, but regardless it can be injected, however singletons have to handle concurrent requests, they really have to be required to consider using.

```
private readonly IWorkerInterface _worker;

public ControllerConstructor(IWorkerInterface worker){
  //Assign variable to controller variable
  _worker = worker ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(worker));
}

[HttpGet("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(){
  return await Task<IActionResult>.Factory.StartNew(() => {
      //TODO: Your lengthy task here
      _worker.DoWork();
  });
}
```

what You get with async await pattern is that the thread is freed up to serve as soon as the task is created from factory and a wait handle is created and that is really flippin' fast, only to be required again once the task has completed.

If you want a threadsafe queue consider using the ConcurrentQueue

the problem with the background worker, as i see it is that it is not a thread pool, unless it needs it, and a thread pool is already at Your disposal through the task.factory

After all if we really want a queue and not handle our work up front, wouldn't we want it persistent, so that once controller has accepted request, it cannot be lost on server crash? then You need to consider another technology than one which lives and dies with the webserver.

Now you could have your webserver publishing on a topic on a persistent service bus which is subscribed to by your background worker only to be completed when processing actually succeeded ... i think what You have in mind is something like this, but i fear that trying to build it into the webservers RAM storage will ultimately give you headaches.

Comment: `Now say you wanted a worker type object, does it have to be a singleton?` already worker service is not singleton in this case. So I'm using EventQueue as singleton. Anyway I'm asking regardless of the this case. Creating task queue and executing one by one or creating new task with Task.Factory.StartNew() at the time. which approach is the best way? You can comment in safety, performance, health? please

Comment: I think, creating queue is truer the other way. The second way is too many will create task instance for this reason will directly affect performance.

Comment: @mrpetrisah not sure i completely understand, but yea so when you add  task, unlike a normal thread, you queue the method on an app pool and it begins as soon as you create it , regardless if it sits in a queue. This is a good approach in the sense that you can control how many workers there may be in your thread pool, but the queue only serves to check results in effect and possibly requeue. so your processing queue is a bit lost. The async await means that then the requests will be queued if you specify fewer workers, but if you do not want processing to happen use Thread instead

Comment: @mrpetrisah if your webserver has too many requests, the http protocol has a backlog concept so it queues the requests, you can decide your concurrency that way and also can define how many threads processes your webserver can use if you have very long running operations that could cause congestion.
So for performance i recommend looking into ThreadPool.MinThreads and ThreadPool.MaxThreads.
And webserver has typically way to also specify threads for primary offload, like if Kestrel: UseKestrel(opts => opts.ThreadCount = 4) but having more than one affects DI so experiment.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Channel<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels?view=netcore-3.1) class that is designed specifically for producer/consumer scenario like this. For your use case, say if you have a message class to send to your queue like:

```
class Message { public int AmountToIncrement { get; set; } }
```

You can register `Channel<Message>`, `ChannelReader<Message>` and `ChannelWriter<Message>` as singletons:

```
services.AddSingleton<Channel<Message>>(Channel.CreateUnbounded<Message>());
services.AddSingleton<ChannelReader<Message>>(svc => svc.GetRequiredService<Channel<Message>>().Reader);
services.AddSingleton<ChannelWriter<Message>>(svc => svc.GetRequiredService<Channel<Message>>().Writer);
```

So now you can inject `ChannelWriter<Message>` to where you want to send message, and `ChannelReader<Message>` to your background service (via constructor, for example). Your `ExecuteAsync` can use `ChannelReader<T>.ReadAsync` to wait for message and process it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For such task I would suggest taking a look at [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=net-5.0) collection.

This should provide a thread safe collection without need for any locks.
Alternatively You could use SemaphoreSlim object as a lock, if You cannot use aforementioned queue.

As far as I know, using ConcurrentQueue should remove the access block You mentioned. If You go with SemaphoreSlim, then I would suggest a small Task.Delay() in background service loop.

As for improvement, You could always try to remodel this service to make use of events, so when something is added to queue, background service will then start processing until nothing is left.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It's was spot on for problem.